# Does ASP.NET on IIS use a thread per request?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis

### Benefits of reducing threadcount

It is fashionable these days to attempt to improve the scalability of web-servers by reducing the number of threads handling requests, in an effort to prevent unnecessary context switching from having tens or hundreds of threads.  This is particularly important when waiting on some kind of application event for a 'long polling' (aka COMET) request - it simply is rude to consume all the resources of an entire thread and do nothing with it.

### Node.ns as an extreme example

Node.ns is a rather extreme example of reducing thread-count, requiring handlers to give up the single thread handling all HTTP requests when waiting on any event (even I/O from a local disk!).  In this way, a CPU core is kept busy doing useful computational work, instead of 'wasting' instructions pausing and resuming many different threads.

### But API support is needed

However, arranging for resumption of the handler once the waited-for event has completed typically requires explicit support in the handler API.  For example, there is a part of the Java Servlet Specification which deals specifically with 'asynchronous' responses.

### Wherefore, ASP.NET?

So, does ASP.NET have a similar API for asynchronous responses (aka. continuations, aka. (a bit loosely) 'reactor pattern')?  Is there authoritative documentation which directly addresses this matter and its interaction with IIS?  What nomenclature does ASP.NET / IIS use to refer to these properties?

I am coming to IIS/.NET shortly, and don't want to write any code that's unnecessarily 'thread-per-request' if I can help it.  I'll be using C# by preference.

Comment: I suggest you search for "asynchronous ASP.NET" - you'll find a *lot* of reading material.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes those are the pages I am looking for.

Comment: @DavidBullock - I suggest reading Jon Skeet's [C# In Depth, 3rd Edition](http://www.amazon.com/Depth-3rd-Edition-Jon-Skeet/dp/161729134X). :-)

Comment: @DavidBullock I will second that recommendation - Manning often have offers on eBooks around Christmas and New Year, so you will most likely be able to pick it up for a good price. There is however a lot of extremely good material from Microsoft and third party sources on async/await in ASP.NET using C# available online.